# Return row number of certain text in array

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1it8_hepj0BAn1xaKbfmtzkKQtUo83wfQHB9SsJ8vojw/edit#gid=0

It looks like this:

[image]

I need a formula that states in which row certain string is written in.
Let's say, if the string is "Pants" answer should be 2.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize `MAP()` function-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";1;(MAP(A1:D;LAMBDA(x;IF(x=F2;ROW(x);"")))))
```

`TEXTJOIN()` for, if there any possibilities to have multiple matches.

And a simple approach could be-

```
=MAX(INDEX(--((A1:D=F2)*ROW(A1:D))))
```

[image]